# How to check that application was installed to registered email address

Tags: android

I want to check whether the Application is being installed by the unique user or not.

Is there any way to check that application's previous version was installed to the android device based on the registered email address?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless your app requires activation, etc. to start and you are keeping a database of user email addresses. If you are trying to keep piracy, etc. in check, you might want to look at [Android licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) (LVL). It will check with Google servers that the current user actually bought the app. Only works for paid apps. You can do something similar for free apps with in-app billing.